# How to show only tagged CPT categories / taxonomies for a custom post type?

Tags: terms, advanced-taxonomy-queries

The code below is echoing all the taxonomies available for the particular CPT. I'm calling this in a `single-posttype.php` to show taxonomies. What I need is to display only the taxonomies tagged to the current post instead of displaying all the taxonomies available.

```
<?php
    $taxonomy   = 'map_feature';
    $terms      = get_terms($taxonomy);

    if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
  ?>

    <ul>
      <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>

        <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></li>

      <?php } ?>

    </ul>

<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Please help me !

Answer (score 0):

`wp_get_object_terms`!

For example, if we want to grab all terms in a `product` taxonomy for a post we might do:

```
$product_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID,  'product' );
if ( ! empty( $product_terms ) ) {
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $product_terms ) ) {
        echo '<ul>';
            foreach( $product_terms as $term ) {
                echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->slug, 'product' ) . '">' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</a></li>'; 
            }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```